# Apache Ignite Query config

Tags: c#, ignite

I am upgrading to Apache Ignite v2.7.6 queries but getting an error with a very simple query configuration. The guidance on QueryEntity seems simple enough but the error message says "Queries are not configured". Hoping someone can show how this is done.

```
              try
                {
                    QueryEntity qEntity = new QueryEntity( typeof( int ), typeof( User ) );
                    var myCache = IgniteEngine.GetOrCreateCache<int, User>( new CacheConfiguration( nameof( "MyCache" ), qEntity ) );
                    var myCacheQueryable = myCache.AsCacheQueryable();//Exception thrown here
                    var result = myCacheQueryable.Where( x => ( x.Key == 12345 ) && x.Value.FirstName == "Peter" ).ToList();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                     //Exception message: Queries are not configured for cache 'MyCache'
                }
```

Comment: I tried your code - it does not compile because `nameof("MyCache")` is not a valid expression. However, if I fix this issue, everything works as expected, here is full runnable project that I tried: https://gist.github.com/ptupitsyn/30adbc0eda2faf6b70d291b23d5aecc1

Comment: Many thanks. Yes this works very well.